# How to start nm-applet in xmonad?

Tags: networkmanager, xmonad

I failed to run the `nm-applet` command, here is the error message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

(nm-applet:25799): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:8:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong, and what should I do?

(Ubuntu + xmonad, without Gnome)

Answer (score 3):

I figure out that the reason `nm-applet` could not start is:

```
There's neither status bar nor system tray in my xmonad configuration.
```

Solution:

1. Start `nm-applet` within `stalonetray`. Or
2. Using `nmcli` command line.

Both of these two methods works fine for me. I hope this would be helpful to other newcomers as well.